# Binary searching with a bubble sorting

Tags: c, loops

I want this code to generate 25 random numbers in the range 1 - 100 and then write "Index of 42 …".
I should write a `printf("Number 42 does not exist")` when number 42 hasn't been generated…
from which what I understand is my code should search for number 42 two times but it's making the code not working

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

void Rand_numb (int array[], int length, int max);
void Binary_search (int b[], int e, int l, int r);

int main()
{
   srand(time(NULL));

   int a[25];
   Rand_numb (a, 25, 200);
   Binary_search( a, 42, 0, 100);

    for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 25; j++)
        {
            if (a[j] > a[j + 1])
            {
               int temp = a[j];
                a[j] = a[j + 1];
                a[j + 1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++)
        printf("%i \n", a[i]);
        printf("the number 42 is at index: %d \n" ,Binary_search);

    return 0;
}

void Rand_numb (int array[], int length, int max)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++)
        array[i] = (rand() % 100) + 1;
}

void Binary_search (int b[], int e, int l, int r)
{
    int mid = l + (r -1)/2;

    if ( l > r) return -1;

    if (b[mid] == e)
        return mid;
    else if (b[mid] > e)
        return Binary_search (b, e, l, (mid - 1));
    else
        return Binary_search (b, e, r, (mid + 1));
}
```

Comment: Is the compiler not complaining about any of the basic mistakes in the code?

Comment: Please clarify: do you want to find the index of the target number in the *original* order from random generation, or in the *sorted* order?

Comment: I see no reason to think that running your binary search twice would cause an error. But you're not doing that.  And, as that search is presently written, running it any number of times does not yield any useful result.

Comment: @JohnBollinger at first I just wanted to make a random number generator that sorted the number and then find a number in this exemple 42. I just wanted too see if I understand binary search and bubble sorting

Comment: Ok, it sounds like that would be "I want to find the index of the target number in the sorted order."  That's important because binary search works only on sorted inputs, so it would be trickier to get the original index of the target number by use of binary search.

Comment: Now, what about those compiler errors / warnings?  If you don't see any then turn up the diagnostic level or get a better compiler.  They are there to help you.  Resolve the issues they point out to you.

Comment: @JohnBollinger So is my binary searching code wrong ? becasue the bubble sorting is working and the random numbers is working to... I understand that binary searcing work like look at the middle element if that is the numer write "number 42 is at index 10. if the number is higher then the element look at (the middle element + 1)  and if its lower look at the  (the middle element - 1) right?

Comment: Now, **what about those compiler errors / warnings**?

Comment: @JohnBollinger 
1. this 'for' clause does not guard for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++)
2. format '%i' expects argument of type 'int', but argument 2 has type 'void' 
3. unused parameter 'length' 
4. unused parameter 'max'
5. "in function binary_search" return with a value, in function returning void (return: -1)
6. return with a value, in function returning void (return: mid)

Comment: With all those errors, it does not really make sense to think about searching twice or similar.This can only become an issue after you managed to compile your program. Most of these message are rather straight forward.

Comment: @Polly, I did not ask you to *list* them, I suggested that you ***fix*** them.  That may require you to spend some time to figure out the nature of the program deficiencies they are complaining about.  (But if you do list them, then that should be edited into the question, not posted in comments.)

Comment: Are you _required_ to have `Binary_search` be _recursive_? It's simpler, faster, easier if it's not.

Comment: If you compile with `-Wall`, then `printf("the number 42 is at index: %d \n" ,Binary_search);` would be flagged. You're trying to print a _pointer_ value (pointer to `Binary_search`) and _not_ an `int`. That's because a function name (e.g. `foo`) by itself is the _address_ of the function. To _invoke_ it, you have to add parentheses (e.g. `foo()`).

Answer (score 0):

`Binary_Search` should return the index where it finds the number or `-1` if the number is not found. You should call the function **after** sorting the array and test this result to report the index or the failure message.

Note also that `int mid = l + (r - 1) / 2;` should use `l` instead of `1`. Avoid naming a variable `l` as it looks obviously confusingly close to `1`.

There are other mistakes in the code, here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

void Rand_numb(int array[], int length, int max);
void Binary_search(int b[], int e, int lo, int hi);

int main() {

    int a[25];

    /* generate the pseudo random numbers */
    srand(time(NULL));
    Rand_numb(a, 25, 200);

    /* sort the array */
    for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 25 - 1; j++) {
            if (a[j] > a[j + 1]) {
                int temp = a[j];
                a[j] = a[j + 1];
                a[j + 1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }

    /* try and locate 42 */
    int index = Binary_search(a, 42, 0, 100);

    if (index < 0) {
        printf("the number 42 is in the array\n");
    } else {
        printf("the number 42 is at index: %d\n", index);
    }
    return 0;
}

void Rand_numb(int array[], int length, int max) {
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        array[i] = (rand() % max) + 1;
}

int Binary_search(int b[], int e, int lo, int hi) {
    if (lo >= hi)
        return -1;

    int mid = lo + (hi - lo) / 2;
    if (b[mid] == e)
        return mid;
    else if (b[mid] > e)
        return Binary_search(b, e, lo, mid);
    else
        return Binary_search(b, e, mid + 1, hi);
}
```